# Delete lines which maching certain criteria

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

There are multiple input files(eg:file1,file2,file3....) each file contain some lines as below.

file 1:

```
123,WoW,45,2018,M_SILVER    
124,WoW_HD,2018,M_SILVER    
125,WoW,45,2018,M_SILVER_FTTH    
126,WoW,45,2018,M_GOLD
```

file 2:

```
133,WoW,45,2019,M_SILVER    
134,WoW_HD,2019,M_SILVER    
135,WoW,45,2019,M_SILVER_FTTH    
136,WoW,45,2019,M_GOLD
```

I need to delete lines which contained WoW and (M_SILVER or M_GOLD) output should contained only lines as below.

file 1:

```
124,WoW_HD,2018,M_SILVER    
125,WoW,45,2018,M_SILVER_FTTH
```

file 2:

```
134,WoW_HD,2019,M_SILVER    
135,WoW,45,2019,M_SILVER_FTTH
```

File name can't be changed.
Hope now the question is clear and you guys can provide a solution.

Tried something like below:

```
ls | grep file| sort | while read line ; do cat $line | grep WoW |grep -v WoW_HD | grep 'M_SILVER\|M_GOLD' | sed -i '/$line/d' ./infile;done
```

Comment: More details please, sample inputs, expected output etc.  Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited the post now. Hope now its clear

Comment: It seems for me like you want a finished solution and dont show any effort. What have you tried? Whats your current code and what is not working in that code?

Comment: Select codes, click the `{}` button on the editor, don't use double newlines, that makes the post hard to read.

Comment: Edited the post to make it readable...

Comment: I used liux command something like below. but its not succeeded.

ls | grep file  | sort | while read line ; do cat $line | grep WoW |grep -v WoW_HD | grep 'M_SILVER\|M_GOLD' | sed -i '/$line/d' ./infile;done

Comment: Your file2's expected output is not right.

Comment: Corrected it...

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want something like this:

```
$ awk -F, '!($2=="WoW" && ($5~"^M_(SILVER|GOLD) *$"))' file1
124,WoW_HD,2018,M_SILVER
125,WoW,45,2018,M_SILVER_FTTH

$ awk -F, '!($2=="WoW" && ($5~"^M_(SILVER|GOLD) *$"))' file2
134,WoW_HD,2019,M_SILVER
135,WoW,45,2019,M_SILVER_FTTH
```

If you have GNU awk 4.1.0+, you can add `-i inplace` switch to replace file(s) in place.
Change `file1`/`file2` to `file*` or other to match multiple files.
Or like you did before, `ls` and feed to `xargs` and pipe to `awk`.

Comment: Your text matching part is okay. 
But deleting non matching lines is not clear.
How to use -i inplace ? (i'm having GNU Awk 3.1.8)

Comment: Define `clear`. I'm providing you solution, not giving your line-to-line tutorial. It's your responsibility to state clear in question not mine in answer.  `3.1.8` not supported, change to other way instead. @user2650100

Comment: Thanks for your support. But i don't know how to use -i option with above awk command. (sorry as i don't have previous experience with this)

awk -F, '!($2=="WoW" && ($5~"^M_(SILVER|GOLD) *$"))' file1

Comment: @user2650100  Update your `awk` version, or use temp file and rename afterwards.

Comment: I have upgraded Awk version
GNU Awk 4.1.3

since i'm having 100+ files, creating temp files and renaming it is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

normaly a sed or a grep is enough

```
sed -i -e '/,Wow,.*,M_SILVER$/d;/,Wow,.*,M_GOLD$/d' file[1-9]*
```

comment on your line:

```
ls | grep file| sort | while read line ; do cat $line | grep WoW |grep -v WoW_HD | grep 'M_SILVER\|M_GOLD' | sed -i '/$line/d' ./infile;done


ls | grep file| sort | while read line ; do cat $line ... ;done
```

this is not needed here, `ls *file*` is enough, you don't need a sort, and use the ls possibility directly. using it to cat the file, use it in a for loop with the file makeing directly
    for File in file*; do ... ;done

```
cat $line | grep WoW |grep -v WoW_HD | grep 'M_SILVER\|M_GOLD' |
```

grep can do all of this in one line (with your data format).
    grep -v ',Wow,.*,(M_SILVER\|M_GOLD)' $File > NewFile

```
| sed -i '/$line/d' ./infile
```

this will request to sed to "select line with the pattern having the word `line` after the end of the line and delete it, other are unchanged"  from and modifying the file ./infile. 
    you copy/paste part of code on sed without understanding what you do nor read about it, a bit dangerous. This part of code is not needed (and useless) for the prupose already done before this part of the line.